# passing a string parameter when calling a method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this method in cs page:

```
public String getToolTip(Object productId, Object imgBtnId)
{
    return UtilsStatic.getWishListButtonToolTip(Int32.Parse(productId.ToString()), getCumparaturiCategoryID(imgBtnId.ToString()));
}
```

and i want to call it from asp.net page (aspx).

I tried like this but it fails:

```
 ToolTip="<%# getToolTip(getProductIdNoutatiFeatured(), 'imgBtnWishSubcategory2Featured')%>"/>
```

Please note that the second parameter is an hardcoded string...but it says:

> CS1012: Too many characters in character literal

I think it is wrong to put the string between ' '. But how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use single quotes for a string, you have to reverse the usage of single- and double-quotes:

```
ToolTip='<%# getToolTip(getProductIdNoutatiFeatured(),
                        "imgBtnWishSubcategory2Featured")%>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
ToolTip="<%# getToolTip(getProductIdNoutatiFeatured(), \"imgBtnWishSubcategory2Featured\")%>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as well as the quotes issue you are trying to use the binding <%# %> instead of writing out the result with a starndard response.write

try

```
'<%=getToolTip(getProductIdNoutatiFeatured(), "imgBtnWishSubcategory2Featured")%>'
```